# Android Studio - java classes get opened as decompiled classes

Tags: android-studio

I have searched for the solution to my problem for a few days, but no luck so far, therefore I decided to begin a new thread. Over a week ago, after an ordinary merge of two branches (meaning - I am quite sure there was nothing to the merge itself that might have caused this problem), all Java classes in my project tree have become unopenable. Every file in the project tree has this icon now:

[image: working tree]

Whenever I try to open one of them, an empty file opens with a "Decompiled .class file" message at the top.

The problem doesn't appear in Intellij IDEA, Xamarin or any other environment. When I go to the project directory on my disk, I can see the code, so it's not like I'm pulling already decompiled classes from my repository.

I tried updating Android Studio, reinstalling it, marking packages including these .java classes explicitly as Sources from Project Structure menu, as well as invalidating cache / restarting / cloning project to a new directory. None of these approaches worked and so I ran out of ideas.

If anyone happened to face the same problem, feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you somehow introduced your own project output/artifacts as a library dependency?  I could see this sort of thing happening if the same class names started appearing in both your project code and in your libraries.  Then again, those icons look like they're suppose to represent binary files.  Can you confirm that you've opened these .java files in another editor like Notepad, and can see that they are still text?

Comment: Thank you for your input. No, I didn't introduce my own project output/artifacts as a library dependency. This is a project going on for a long time and I would have noticed this behaviour before if that had been the case. Also, I opened these files in Sublime Text and they are, indeed, still text. As I mentioned in the post, the problem doesn't appear in IntelliJ, Xamarin, or any other environment/editor I tried.

Comment: Have you tried shutting down Android Studo and completely deleting its system and config folders?  Those aren't usually removed on uninstall, and purging the cache may not be enough.  You can figure out their default location by peeking in the `idea.properties` file, which should be in the `bin` folder alongside `idea[64].exe`.  Deleting those folders will effectively put you in a factory clean state.  You'll potentially lose a bunch of settings, but I imagine you're okay with that at this point :).

Comment: Your solution is working. Thank you very much :)